# Two column layout with form

Tags: columns, forms, parallel, javascript

So here is the basic idea: 2 column Layout, 1 column with text and 1 column with a form you can fill in Acrobat Reader etc. I tried to use `parallel` and/or `paracol` package along with the `hyperref` `\eform` form stuff sadly I failed miserably. There is probably some Java scripting involved.

Comment: Can you show your failed code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). As @HarishKumar suggested it would be helpful to see what you attempted in order to determine exactly what failed.  Also, not sure `Adobe Reader` can be used to fill PDF forms? I thought you needed `Acrobat Pro` for that?

Answer (score 9):

The two column layout is possible using the `multicol` package. You can keep content in the two columns separate by putting

```
\vfill
\columnbreak
```

after the content in the left hand column. The form is made using the `hyperref` package and its appearance and format can be changed using options that are explained in the [`hyperref` manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html).

Here is a MWE that combines all of these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{Column with Text}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vfill
\columnbreak

\section{Column with Form}
\begin{Form}[]
    \noindent\TextField[name=name,borderwidth=1pt]{Name:}\\[5mm]
    \TextField[name=email,borderwidth=1pt]{E-mail:}\\[5mm]
    \TextField[name=university,borderwidth=1pt]{University:}\\[5mm]
\end{Form}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer! But unfortunately that is pretty similar to my solution that doesn't work somehow

<blink>\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{1 Text}
\lipsum[1]
%\vfill

\section{2 Text}
\lipsum[1]

\columnbreak

\section{Your comments here:}
\begin{Form}[]
    \noindent\TextField[name=comments,multiline=true,height=2in,width=3in,borderwidth=0,backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]{}\\\\[5mm]
\end{Form}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}</blink>

Comment: sorry could not figure out within the 5mins of editing time how to put in a code ... so much for my programming skills !
<br>
Problem still remains there is no page break happening and even if it would page break the comment box would not be displayed again.
<br>
what i would like to happen is that the right column always has a comment box while the left column continues

Comment: ok guys, is there a way to page break a realllllllly long marginpar ?

Comment: @zwck I don't have a solution in mind right now given the new requirements. I'll see if I can figure something out and edit my answer when I do.